$M^{\perp \perp}$ is the smallest closed subspace containing M

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $M$ an arbitrary subset. Show that $M^{\perp \perp}$ is the smallest closed subspace of $H$ that contains $M$.

I have checked this Smallest closed subspace which contains $M$ which assumes WLOG that $M$ is itself already a closed subspace. I am wondering if proving that $\overline{\text{span}(M)}=M^{\perp \perp}$ works for this problem, and if so, whether my solution is correct:

It’s clear that $ M^{\perp \perp} $ is a closed subspace because for any arbitrary subset $ S $ of $ H $, $ S^{\perp} $ is a closed subspace. It is also clear that $ M \subset M^{\perp \perp} $.
Take the closure of $ \text{span}(M) $. Since $ \text{span} \, M $ is a subspace containing $ M $, $ \text{span} \, (M) \subset M^{\perp \perp} $. Then $ \overline{\text{span} \, M} \subset M^{\perp \perp} $. We shall show that $ M^{\perp \perp} \subset \overline{\text{span} \, M} $.
If $ \overline{\text{span} \, M} $ is indeed a proper subspace of $ M^{\perp \perp} $, then we can find $ x \in M^{\perp \perp} \setminus \overline{\text{span} \, M} $. Since $ H $ is a Hilbert space and $ M^{\perp \perp} $ is a closed subspace, $ M^{\perp \perp} $ is a Hilbert space as well. We can write $ x = x' + y' $ where $ x' \in \overline{\text{span} \, M} $ and $ y' \in (\overline{\text{span} \, M})^{\perp} $, with $ y' \neq 0 $.
Observe that $ (\overline{\text{span} \, M})^{\perp} \subset M^{\perp} $, so $ y' \in M^{\perp} $. Also, $ \overline{\text{span} \, M} \subset M^{\perp \perp} $: if $ \overline{x} \in \overline{\text{span} \, M} $, then there is a sequence $ \{ x_1, x_2, \dots \} $ in $ \text{span} \, M $ converging to $ \overline{x} $. For each $ x_i $ in the sequence and $ y \in M^{\perp} $, $ \langle x_i, y \rangle = 0 $, so $ \langle \overline{x}, y \rangle = 0 $.
So $ x = x' + y' $ for $ x' \in M^{\perp} $ and $ y' \in M^{\perp \perp} $, with $ y' \neq 0 $. Also, we can write $ x = x + 0 $ since $ x \in M^{\perp \perp} $. However, since $ H $ is a Hilbert space, $ H = M^{\perp} \oplus M^{\perp \perp} $. This means that $ x $ can only be written in one way as the sum of an element in $ M^{\perp} $ and an element in $ M^{\perp \perp} $. This is a contradiction.

